# Is it possible to open a lightbox from an external link inside an Epub?

Tags: hyperlink, joomla, external, lightbox

I'm a writer.

I'm creating an enhanced Epub novel with Sigil.
Within the novel, I display small size pictures. For each picture, I want the reader to click on the legend below the picture that will direct them directly to the picture in a lightbox (or modal or featherlight) on my future website with a code like this :

```html
<p>
<a href="https://example.com/#picture_opened_in_a_lightbox">Picture of Redwoods</a>
</p>
```

When the reader closes the lightbox (or modal or featherlight), the page of my website, where a smaller sized image (along with other smaller pictures)is displayed, appears.

My future website will be with Joomla 3 with Astroid Framework/template.

I read about BS modal, BS lightbox, Featherlight but I'm lost. I want to do my own clean code with the least plugins/modules possible.

Is it possible to make a link (from an Epub or even an other webpage) to an opened "lightbox (modal ?) image" on a website ? And when you close the lightbox/modal image, the page containing the lightboxe/modal code appears ?

Thanks a lot.

Lise

Comment: Are you planning on building your "future website" on Joomla 3 or Joomla 4?  We are at an awkward time right now, as Joomla 4 is nearly released and then there will be the hard slog of upgrading a world-full of J3 sites to J4.  If time allows, you might save yourself some toil and decide to build directly in J4.  If you are (or will be) a Joomla user, please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hi, I'm already a Joomla user. My first website (https://www.disfrutelanaturaleza.com) is on Joomla 3. I plan on putting my future( joomla) website online in september or october.  Joomla 4 hasn't been released yet so I'm warry to use it.